# Run other code while awaiting

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, trading, cryptocurrency

This is probably a stupid question, but my current project is stuck until I figure it out.

Say I have this function.

```
async function AtoB() {
   try{
      await ACheck();
      let quantity = (ABalance - (1 / ABuy));
      quantity = parseFloat(quantity.toFixed(4));
      exchange.createMarketBuyOrder('A/B', quantity)
      trade();
   } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
   }
}
```

The function is awaiting another function called ACheck() that looks like this:

```
async function ACheck() {
   while(ABalance/ABuy < 10) {
   }
   return true;
}
```

My issue is that ABalance and ABuy are set in another function that gets their values using CCXT. When AtoB() runs, it stops a setTimeout I have in place that calls the price function every 5 seconds. This effectively means that the function will never run since the values for ABalance and Abuy never update.

Is there any way to run the prices function at the same 5 seconds intervals while awaiting ACheck()?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `ACheck` is blocking the process. If you do this, all else will halt on the js side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to block the main thread if you want to run other things async.

Just have your `setTimeout` run like it does now, when it fires, calculate `ABalance/ABuy`. If `Abalance/Abuy < 10`, do nothing and wait for next `setTimeout` to fire. If not, do the rest.